# How to decode a text with unicodes like \u00e7 in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

Hi I receive texts from via library, when I print the received text I see some non-english characters as "\u00e7" which must be "ç" instead. I guess somehow I need to encode and re-decode the text, but I am very new to python and I do not if it is the right approach. Can you please enlighten my way?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7.5 I think it is latest and greatest.

Comment: Latest is python 3.3.3. This does matter as the handling of unicode strings changed from 2.x to 3.x.

Comment: Can you show us the text you get, in the form you see it in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decode the string using [`unicode_escape` encoding](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings):

```
>>> s = r'\u00e7'
>>> print s
\u00e7
>>> print s.decode('unicode-escape')
ç
>>>
```

If `sys.stdout.encoding` is `ascii`, print will raise `UnicodeEncodeError`; In such case, encode it explicitly:

```
>>> print s.decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf-8')
ç
```

Comment: This could be the right answer, but with the amount of information the OP has given so far, it's impossible to tell. I doubt it's right; my guess would be that either the OP already has unicode objects, or he needs to decode it as JSON. Not many sources provide data in the form of Python unicode string literals, which is what `unicode-escape` handles.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It is probably the right answer but I am still missing something. I have this error not on decoding line but the print line.
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0131' in position 135: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @smart-dev.org: It sounds like you already have a Unicode string. That's the error message you get when you try to re-decode a Unicode string and the Unicode string contains non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @smart-dev.org, Try `s.decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf-8')`.

Comment: @smart-dev.org, BTW, where does the string come from? What library do you use?

Comment: @user2357112 The object pointer is httplib.HTTPSConnection(xxx).getresponse().read()

Comment: @falsetru I am using tweepy, to stream data from twitter.

Comment: @falsetru it is working like charm. Can you post is as an answer?